# p:dataTable "No records found." while a non empty list is manually returned

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, lazy-loading

The log shows that I indeed call the LazyDataModel.load() method but the tables shows no records.

```
<p:dataTable var="user" value="#{adminLazyBean.lazyDataModel}"
            paginator="true" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
            id="carTable" lazy="true"
            paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">

            <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{user.id}" filterBy="#{user.id}">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.id}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{user.name}"
                filterBy="#{user.name}">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Username" sortBy="#{user.username}"
                filterBy="#{user.username}">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.username}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Phonenumber" sortBy="#{user.phoneNumber}"
                filterBy="#{user.phoneNumber}">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.phoneNumber}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Here is my load method.

```
@Override
    public List<UserDTO> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
            Map<String, Object> filters) {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LazyAdmin.class.getName());
        log.debug("LOAD CALLED");
        UserDTO u = new UserDTO();
        u.setName("DUMMY");
        List<UserDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(u);
        return list;
         }
}
```

As you can see i return a list with one element which name is DUMMY.
I think this should work. I did atleast 5 times run through the example code and could not find anything.

Comment: Did you store an instance of `LazyDataModel<T>` into the managed bean `AdminLazyBean`? If not, then just do `value="#{adminLazyBean}"` in `<p:dataTable>`.

Comment: yes I did. And it is initialized PostCunstruct and the bean is ViewScoped

Comment: Do you use an anonymous class for sure? Thus, the managed bean class itself does not extend `LazyDataModel<T>` like `public class AdminLazyBean extends LazyDataModel<UserDTO> implements Serializable {...}`.

Comment: People may think I'm whining, but from now on I'm not going to ask the questions @Tiny is asking anymore. Just point to [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and post version info and compare with the PrimeFaces showcase (hint: setting the rowcount)

Comment: @Kukeltje next time ill be more specific. Thank you for your hint. I already tried this like an hour ago but I found out that there was another problem and forgot to use this solution again.

Comment: @Tiny I'm grateful for your help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lazyDataModel.setRowCount(2);` solved the problem.